# Ubuntu 16.04 - Cannot Open PhpMyAdmin after do full installation

Tags: nginx, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

I have minor problem here. I try to install phpmyadmin in my machine. Before I start install phpmyadmin, I have done installing LEMP.

Details:

Ubuntu 16.04

Nginx 1.9.15

MySQL 14.14

PHP 7.0.4

Steps for install phpmyadmin I follow here:
[How To Install and Secure phpMyAdmin with Nginx on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)

After I done with installing phpmyadmin then I go to my web browser and click this [http://server_domain_or_IP/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin). It should show up interface of phpmyadmin. But mine show a pop out like this.

[image]

I do not have an idea what is happening. Hope anyone can help me.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like nginx is running but doesn't know how to handle the PHP processing. Try

```
service nginx restart
```

If that doesn't work, try making a basic PHP file in the server root, something like:

```
<?php echo "PHP is working"; ?>
```

And see if you can get that to load properly.

If you pass those two steps and still have trouble, my next guess is that the phpmyadmin site is not properly enabled. Check that the link for the site points to the right place. This talks about virtual hosts (albeit for Ubuntu 12.04 but should work):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

If it still doesn't work, you can download the tar.gz of phpMyAdmin and manually configure to see that it gets going.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I have solved my problem by uninstalling the phpmyadmin and install it back.